# Replicator equation for mixed strategies?

Tags: evolution, natural-selection, theoretical-biology, evolutionary-game-theory

The the replicator equation is usually defined for pure strategies. More specifically, the replicator eqn for $n$ strategies is given by:
\begin{equation}
  \dot x_{i} = x_{i} \left( \sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij}x_{j} - \phi \right)
  \qquad i = 1, \ldots, n
\end{equation}
where $x_i$ is the frequency of the strategy $i$, $A=[a_{ij}]$ is the payoff matrix, and $\phi$ is the average fitness of the population. Basically, what the replicator equation is saying is that the per capita rate of increase of the strategy $i$ (i.e., $\dot x_i/ x_i$) is the difference between the fitness of $i$ (i.e., $\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_{ij}x_{j}$) and the average fitness $\phi$ of the whole population.

**Question:** Does anyone know of a formulation of the replicator eqn for **mixed** strategies?

Comment: When you allow for mixed strategies, you essentially have an infinite strategy set. There is a branch of evolutionary dynamics concerned with infinite strategy spaces. I know of this paper, for example: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/PL00004092